# Azure Notification Hub Registrations fail with some tag formats

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

I'm using Xamarin on iOS against an Azure Notification hub.  Things have been working fine for a while.  But, I recently added a new TAG to a collection of tags that I register my devices against.

Here is abbreviated code that WORKs:

```
NSSet tags = new NSSet("Email-some@some.com");
if (tags != null) {
    Hub.RegisterNativeAsync(deviceToken, tags,(errorCallback) => {
        if (errorCallback != null) {
            new UIAlertView("RegisterNativeAsync error", "Unable to register for Push notifications", null, "OK", null).Show();
            return;
        }
    });                 
}
```

However, if I replace the first line with this content, the RegisterNativeAsync FAILS:

```
NSSet tags = new NSSet("Email-no email provided for some user");
```

I receive this response:

URLRequest failed for  { URL: https://MYNAMESPACE.servicebus.windows.net/MYNOTIFICATIONHUBNAME/Registrations/7659656661665513594-8491925189141493076-8?api-version=2013-04 } with status code: bad request

Are there formatting rules about tags?  I have dozens of other tags with lots of types of content and have never run into this issue before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530749.aspx):

> A tag can be any string, up to 120 characters, containing alphanumeric and the following non-alphanumeric characters: ‘_’, ‘@’, ‘#’, ‘.’, ‘:’, ‘-’.

So in your case **space** breaks the things.

Comment: Wow...not sure how I breezed over that info.  I guess I've been lucky so far not to have illegal content in my tags!